# Simple Spring Boot Project is giving 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot but I am not able to execute the basic "Hello World" program. I have built the basic project using https://start.spring.io/ and updated the code as per below code snippets:

Spring Boot Main Class:

```
package com.rohit.springboot.practice.selfspringboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rohit.springboot.practice.selfspringboot")
public class SelfSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SelfSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller Class:

```
package com.rohit.springboot.practice.selfspringboot;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ThisWorldSpringContainer {
    
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hello-world")
    public String getWelcome() {
        
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rohit.springboot.practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>self-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>self-spring-boot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Error:

```
Message: The requested resource [/hello-world] is not available
```

I know this question has been asked by multiple people but i have gone through those answers and tried those given answers but didn't work.

Technologies used are Java 8, Tomcat 9, Spring Boot 2.6.6 etc.

Kindly help.

Comment: Please, post your code, not images. It is significantly easier for others to copy-paste your code to test it rather than writing all down.

Also, how are you getting this error (What do you do to get it)? Provide your POM file as well.

Comment: Have updated the Q with code snippets and POM.xml file. This error is coming when I am trying to run this project as Run as "Run on Server".

Comment: I've just created a project with the same dependencies and the `pom.xml` differs from yours. Did you modified anything from this file? Usually, with the `spring-web` dependency, you'll find the embedded tomcat, so you can run the project without a standalone server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know that Spring Boot can be executed as  Run as Application due to Embedded Tomcat Container. I generated the project again from the https://start.spring.io/ and updated the code as above & then executed as Run as Application. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have the Tomcat dependency, I'm implying that you want your application to run in a standalone Tomcat instance. Also, given your comment, I believe you're working on either Eclipse or Spring Tools Suite (Which is the same, really).

With that, it seems your problem is the lack of a packaging method. Tomcat needs the code its going to run in a package. This package is a zip-like file with `.war` extension. Maven, the program that handles the dependencies of your project according to the `pom.xml` file, can package it in either `war` of `jar` format. Since you are running it in an external Tomcat, you want the `war` extension. So please, add the following line to your `pom.xml` file. It has to be in the same level as `<name>`:

```xml
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Then, update your project (Alt + F5, check your project and hit OK) then try running your project again. You should see an stylish "SPRING" output in your console.

Now, since you are running this externally, you need to specify the name of the project, so you should call your endpoint with

`http://localhost:8080/<your_project_name_here>/hello-world`

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to check this new change in Spring Boot 2.6 :

[PathPattern Based Path Matching Strategy for Spring MVC](https://%5Bhttps://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#pathpattern-based-path-matching-strategy-for-spring-mvc%5D)

In this release, the default strategy for matching request paths against registered Spring MVC handler mappings has changed from **AntPathMatcher** to **PathPatternParser**.

If you need to switch the default strategy back to **AntPathMatcher**, you can set the property **spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy** to **ant-path-matcher** as in the line below to add in the file **application.properties** :

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

I encountered the same issue of HTTP 404 error when upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6 and adding this property solved my problem and should solve yours.

Answer (score -1):

I have modified your code as below:

```
@RequestMapping
@RestController
public class ThisWorldSpringContainer {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/hello-world")
    public String getWelcome() {
        
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

I thinking you are missing

```
@Requestmapping
```

in classlevel

Comment: I have already tried this but it's not working. 

Error Message: The requested resource [/hello-world] is not available.

URL : http://localhost:8080/hello-world